# wxPython - Trapping Mouse & Keyboard Events without window Focus

Tags: windows, keyboard, wxpython, mouse, message-queue

I am attempting to write a time management tool with wxPython that is ideally non-obtrusive and very much out of the way.  The app so far can be used normally and minimized to the system tray for the duration of its use.

However, I notice that once the frame is not in focus, as it is when its 'Iconized', the mouse and keyboard trapping that normally works when the frame/app is in focus no longer works.

I am aware that I could write a C++ program to create a Message Queue Hook and trap all mouse and keyboard events at the OS level, but Id rather not roll up my sleeves *that* far.  After all trying to avoid getting my hands *that* dirty is why I am writing the UI in wxPython in the first place :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need mouse and keyboard events or would it be sufficient to just know if the user has been idle? (You mentioned a time management app, so this seems feasible.)

This code will work on Windows and returns the idle time in seconds.

```
from ctypes import Structure, windll, c_uint, sizeof, byref

class LASTINPUTINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cbSize', c_uint),
        ('dwTime', c_uint),
    ]

def get_idle_duration():
    lastInputInfo = LASTINPUTINFO()
    lastInputInfo.cbSize = sizeof(lastInputInfo)
    windll.user32.GetLastInputInfo(byref(lastInputInfo))
    millis = windll.kernel32.GetTickCount() - lastInputInfo.dwTime
    return millis / 1000.0
```

Comment: Holy Cow.  Yes I suppose you're right (faceplant).

There was a fantasy about breaking down the user's keyboard time and mouse time but I suppose that might be one of those really really really after-thought and needless type things.

Thank you for this.

Comment: Also .. is this how you combine C and python?  Is it this easy?

Comment: ctypes and pywin32 provide access to Windows APIs.  You can also integrate your own C code into a Python app, but that's different.